# ZIP File Viruses

Tags: windows, windows-10, virus, anti-virus, zip

If I open a ZIP File, and attempt to open an example of "Virus.exe", my antivirus tells me that this file is unsecure or whatever, and I press on Don't run, is there still the possibility of my computer being infected with the virus, even if I pressed don't run? Thanks.

Comment: Not for this particular file. There is the possibility that the anti-virus does not detect the virus, and you get infected then, but I'm not sure this is what you mean with your question.

Comment: Not unless you got a horrible AV product, anything legit won't allow it run.

Comment: As long as you use a solid program to unzip, it should be fine, but some zip packages have the capability to take actions  when unzipped (self-extractors mainly).

Comment: You can scan the zip file without opening it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be safe.  You told your computer not to run the file.

Note that I did say, "*should be*".  I didn't say, "*are*".  Why?

Because there is an ongoing battle between malware authors and people trying to protect computers.  So things don't always happen as one would hope.

A virus is a program.  That means it is a series of steps.  You can think of a program like a recipe.  In theory, knowledge doesn't harm things.  For example, you could have a book describing tons of methods of demolishing bridges.  As long as the book sits on a shelf, there's no active problem.  You could even have a scribe read from the book, and write material in a new book, and there's no problem.  The problem occurs if a youthful unfriendly military commander-wannabe picks up the book and starts destroying the city.

Similarly, zip files and JPEG files are data files.  So zip files should not be able to infect a system.  What causes the system is when the instructions are executed.  In other words, when the series of steps gets performed.  In other words, when a program is run.

Now, here's the problem with that theory.  [MS04-028](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/ms04-028) documents an old bug (I'm picking on something over a decade old here) where Microsoft's web browser, and tons of other Microsoft software, used code to handle JPEG files, and specific data in a JPEG file could cause that software code to start running instructions.  Such a problem was probably caused by Microsoft's attempts to make things happen quickly, prioritizing that more than making things happen securely.  So, the idea that data files cannot infect something is theoretically true, but data can be designed to take advantage of a known problems (such as outright bugs, and violations of trust designs) which may cause (popular) software to start executing code.

So, is there a theory that says your computer may have actually gotten infected when handling a Zip file?  Yes.  That is why I had to back off from a stronger statement, and I simply said that you *should be* safe.